# Duplicate message after getting MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code '2', Reason '2018'

Tags: java, duplicates, ibm-mq

I have the below scenario:

I am putting a message in a MQ queue and some other application is polling in the same queue. I have came across a scenario like this:

My application tries to put the message into the queue, but it experiences **MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code '2', Reason '2018'**. I have a retry logic if my application fails to put the message into the queue. So my application tries to put the message in the queue. This time it is able to put the message in the queue again. Now the problem appear is the other application which was polling the queue for the message, received two messages.

I am using MQ server version 7.0.1.8 and MQ client version 7.0.1.5.

My doubts are as below:

1. Why the message put twice in queue even though the first time I experienced **MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code '2', Reason '2018'**.
2. Is there any **autocommit** flag in MQ? Where can I get more details on this? I have done google on it, but does not get proper information. I checked the below link, but nothing related to MQ autocommit flag. [Committing and backing out units of work](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzal.doc/fg13620_.htm)
3. Is the difference in server version and client version matters?
4. From the [APAR IV22989](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV22989), I have seen there is a fix from IBM for MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code '2', Reason '2018'. Is this only applicable to V7.1 and V7.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'd suggest updating at least the version of the client you are using; 7.0.1.12 is the latest.  Maintenance applied to the QM as well would be useful. The difference in level might be the issue but I would suggest getting a recent level would be a good practice. The design is such that the difference should not matter - especially if using client mode (TCP/IP) this provides an added

I'm assuming that this is the classes for Java and not the JMS API you are using? In this case the commit will be controlled by the choice of the syncpoint options you have selected.

JMS has the concept of auto-acknowledge of messages; sounds like here the message is put outside of syncpoint (transaction) and hence appears on the queue. A problem occurs and the message is put again. Generally this is good practice for the application to respond to errors but without putting in a transaction duplicate message is a risk that is taken.

Comment: Thanks. Got some idea. But still most of the doubts I have raised is not clear.